# Plotting SVM hyperplane margin

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, plotting

I'm trying to understand how to plot SVM hyperplane and its margins by this example:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_margin.html

And I got stuck at the plotting the parallels part:

```
# plot the parallels to the separating hyperplane that pass through the
# support vectors (margin away from hyperplane in direction
# perpendicular to hyperplane). This is sqrt(1+a^2) away vertically in
# 2-d.
margin = 1 / np.sqrt(np.sum(clf.coef_ ** 2))
yy_down = yy - np.sqrt(1 + a ** 2) * margin
yy_up = yy + np.sqrt(1 + a ** 2) * margin
```

At the comment section we see:

> This is sqrt(1+a^2) away vertically in 2-d.

So, my question is why `np.sqrt(1 + a ** 2) * margin` is the vertical distance from a hyperplane to its parallel line? How did we come up with it?

*Note: `a` here is just a slope of a hyperplane, and `margin` is a magnitude of the distance between the hyperplane and the parallel dashed line.

I also drew a picture as I can see the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to trigonometry. The distance between the points in the y axis that you represent here by a red line is calculated by multiplying the distance between the two parallel lines (here represented by the margin) and the `sqrt(1 + a ** 2)`.

You can get to this by using two elements:

1. this equation, often used to represent a line: `y = mx + c`.
2. the slope, since parallel lines have the same slope.

More information can be found in the following link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-distance-between-two-parallel-lines/

Hope this helps.